# Parsing URL to string not working with new Thread

Tags: java, android, string, multithreading, url

I am new to android and the Async task is too hard for me to  implement, so I tried running my URL to string parsing on a new Thread but its not working. The length for the "weather" variable which is supposed to get all data from the URL returns 0

My code:

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        int num1;
                        int num2;
                        int num3;
                        int num4;
                        int num5;



                        String weather="";
                        try {
                            weather = new Scanner(new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat="+lat+"&lon="+longi+"&units=metric&mode=xml").openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        num1=weather.length();

                        String location=Integer.toString(num1);

                        String status="";

                        String xml = "<resp><status>good</status><msg>hi</msg></resp>";

                        XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
                        XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
                        InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(weather));

                        try{
                            status = xpath.evaluate("/weatherdata/location/name", source);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            // e.printStackTrace();
                        }
//System.out.println(weather);
                        System.out.println("weatherdisplay=" + weather);
                        System.out.println("status=" + status);
                        System.out.println("Location display=" + location);


                        textCountry=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);

                        textCountry.setText(location);

                        //Your code goes here
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            thread.start();
```

Comment: You should have stacktraces. Post them here if so.

Answer (score 0):

I can only recomend you to actually implement an AsyncTask.

Those are really easy and are working great.

Please take the time to learn how to implement them and you'll only get happier.

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask
- http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html